# Scanning linear barcodes with QRScanner

Tags: codenameone

I tried both cn1 barcode scanner plugins to scan linear barcodes and I can't make it work using the littlemonkey qrscanner plugin. It works well with EAN / UPC codes but it does not with Code-128.

With the `com.codename1.ext.codescan.CodeScanner` plugin it works if I write:

```
  Display.getInstance().setProperty("android.scanTypes", "CODE_128");
```

This doesn't seem to work with the `org.littlemonkey.qrscanner.QRScanner` plugin.

I also would like to know how do I add more barcode type ? I need to support both Code-128 and UPC-A codes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `;` to separate multiple types.

The littlemonkey lib seems to have hardcoded the barcode types, see: https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner/blob/master/native/android/org/littlemonkey/qrscanner/NativeScannerImpl.java

You can just build a version of your own with the right values or you can submit a pull request to Nick with a more generic solution.